# Why do we make $E \subset X$ in the definition of function limit / continuity?

Tags: real-analysis

In Baby Rudin, in the definitions of continuity, we have metric spaces $X, Y$, a set $E \subset X$, and a function $f : E \to Y$. My question is what is the purpose of this subset $E$? Why don't we just say $f : X \to Y$? I don't see the purpose of introducing $E$ here, since $X$ is an arbitrary metric space.

Indeed, in the definition of uniform continuity, that is exactly what Rudin does. "Let $f$ be a mapping of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$"

Comment: I think $\;E\;$ isn't just "one subset", but *a domain", which is usually required to be non-empty and open (and perhaps even connected, depending on the author and/or case under treatment)

Comment: @Timbuc But Rudin introduces it just as some subset of $X$. I don't see why not just use $X$.

Comment: Indeed, but then immediately after he passes to define "continuity on $\;E\;$", so perhaps he wants to stress the fact that a function can be continuous in some subset of m.s. without having to be so in the whole space.